# Github pages picking readme but not index.html

Tags: angularjs, github, github-pages

I am using github pages to host a single page application which I have been working on. This is my first time using github pages. The project is based on angular js and the structure of project is like

- project:

  - src

    - index.html
    - ...
  - ...

It is a public repo you can see that at https://github.com/ChanikyaMohan/Angular-play

The problem is the github pages is picking up readme file but not index.html.
Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: The gh-pages address should be http://chanikyamohan.github.io/Angular-play. It doesn't work for me. Did you configure it correctly? You have to either push it to `gh-pages` branch or configure a different branch inside project settings. Also note that if your `index.html` is inside `src` folder, the url should be corresponding to this structure, meaning that the page should be available at http://chanikyamohan.github.io/Angular-play/src/

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is my first time with github pages and I did not know I had to to create a new branch for it.

Comment: Thank you @MarkoGrešak . It worked.

Answer (score 2):

your index.html is in the src folder ..
place it in the top of the gh-pages

Comment: create a gh-pages named branch... place your index.html in top of gh-pages.. go to settings of repository and see the url of your application in gh-pages section

Comment: tick the answer then